# Sorting problem ( distortion ) of area chart in VegaLite

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api, vega-embed

I create area chart and add a custom scroller using vconcat composition,vconcat[0] is main chart and vconcat[1](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMJsGszGgBMARgAMlAGwAWJQjn00IAFJJZ-HaKILJICHDeACIASiYgAL4KpuaWaLYA7ACclJli7p4w3gBicEyBtsGh4d4A6gCi0QlJIGYWVqi2YhIuABz5loXoALJIAE7llWER6ADiABI+TcltNgDMjunW-V7oAII440FKVdMgACpzdUstKe22TumU1unbgyAjAJ4Tx1PePgCqAE1rq1UqhVhJ7FsQB4Bn8LN8Qr90HVInFEsswdZVi4ci8YQV4YJESdvABFADKkRBtzS6ScT1e3l2DDIJORIF2AA10c1QXcnKtKD03AS4egKXAcOzqugipEKTSVh1MrZKPZbEz0AB5KCYGWnXZUpVg2w9aw5TJakAAOTYxAN3guNpNd1s2Sy1sicCgjvQ0SKADVXWlrLj0qLYTtfP5AtZJrKQDUKVyQ6gw2qen0xdGSmVrPGfonKbs0-chRrrSNDoWkYmANLagCSZdWj1W1v2NYTp0BcxdGJuyvsVaQXwLPe8fcWg-5aScjjEmpzbx8CInRdO9YAMtqEgBdRIqfRQUY0HCYdjyWZsNhkQRwADkEAABBBMGwoABrF8HGhQOAX3tOBRhfS9wkoYJiCgOQoDUIxQHgGgyCwGwxBHEBBDHECEJAOBZBg5QaFkMg0FAAAPMiQAAMxoOBBGUbwo0KJQZFGdpZAYQRBCUTAPhwU5ZDYBBiJ0JoQA+KjaPoxj0DnVi4IfKiAC8QLYNBqJ0CA4CPPiBO8ABHBh-EvdRL1IBIj2QUYvyo4RZGmTBRj0JQcDYYj2iclyQA-NhBEvHA0C8uBeP404xjgFB4nifdeNGfwIGothRgQXDaP8nDNBAHAxjCbwmGciBCmi2KQAAdxoZRoxgywkGInDB3wwjiNIrKYMEZKqO0XRTmEFDMBmeLJKPSisqQciaAMLKsKYeips0wRtN4-8v3mrSQp8uglNQTjuKPaSGKYwlWOSjiuJ4nywu8ISRNCQRLKUJD+rQFwMOs2ysrYHKoDoSTUAwvTwtGSLxJy+KECm4w61OAqGCK4JtIfPUqKatgiJIyGQEo0qnISrDMEc5yNsB7wPJA7rLNKiqqreGr1Hq0YD3iIA) is for dummy scroller
Issue is that when i drag on scroller (vconcat[1](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMJsGszGgBMARgAMlAGwAWJQjn00IAFJJZ-HaKILJICHDeACIASiYgAL4KpuaWaLYA7ACclJli7p4w3gBicEyBtsGh4d4A6gCi0QlJIGYWVqi2YhIuABz5loXoALJIAE7llWER6ADiABI+TcltNgDMjunW-V7oAII440FKVdMgACpzdUstKe22TumU1unbgyAjAJ4Tx1PePgCqAE1rq1UqhVhJ7FsQB4Bn8LN8Qr90HVInFEsswdZVi4ci8YQV4YJESdvABFADKkRBtzS6ScT1e3l2DDIJORIF2AA10c1QXcnKtKD03AS4egKXAcOzqugipEKTSVh1MrZKPZbEz0AB5KCYGWnXZUpVg2w9aw5TJakAAOTYxAN3guNpNd1s2Sy1sicCgjvQ0SKADVXWlrLj0qLYTtfP5AtZJrKQDUKVyQ6gw2qen0xdGSmVrPGfonKbs0-chRrrSNDoWkYmANLagCSZdWj1W1v2NYTp0BcxdGJuyvsVaQXwLPe8fcWg-5aScjjEmpzbx8CInRdO9YAMtqEgBdRIqfRQUY0HCYdjyWZsNhkQRwADkEAABBBMGwoABrF8HGhQOAX3tOBRhfS9wkoYJiCgOQoDUIxQHgGgyCwGwxBHEBBDHECEJAOBZBg5QaFkMg0FAAAPMiQAAMxoOBBGUbwo0KJQZFGdpZAYQRBCUTAPhwU5ZDYBBiJ0JoQA+KjaPoxj0DnVi4IfKiAC8QLYNBqJ0CA4CPPiBO8ABHBh-EvdRL1IBIj2QUYvyo4RZGmTBRj0JQcDYYj2iclyQA-NhBEvHA0C8uBeP404xjgFB4nifdeNGfwIGothRgQXDaP8nDNBAHAxjCbwmGciBCmi2KQAAdxoZRoxgywkGInDB3wwjiNIrKYMEZKqO0XRTmEFDMBmeLJKPSisqQciaAMLKsKYeips0wRtN4-8v3mrSQp8uglNQTjuKPaSGKYwlWOSjiuJ4nywu8ISRNCQRLKUJD+rQFwMOs2ysrYHKoDoSTUAwvTwtGSLxJy+KECm4w61OAqGCK4JtIfPUqKatgiJIyGQEo0qnISrDMEc5yNsB7wPJA7rLNKiqqreGr1Hq0YD3iIA)) for scroll and single click on the same (scroller) then chart get distorted.[image: chart distord, x axis label is correct]
I am using sort by id to maintain the sorting on x axis
And if i set sort to null then x-axis label sort get wrong (not in order as expected)

[image: when sort is set null then x axis label get wrong]

Editor link--[vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMJsGszGgBMARgAMlAGwAWJQjn00IAFJJZ-HaKILJICHDeACIASiYgAL4KpuaWaLYA7ACclJli7p4w3gBicEyBtsGh4d4A6gCi0QlJIGYWVqi2YhIuABz5loXoALJIAE7llWER6ADiABI+TcltNgDMjunW-V7oAII440FKVdMgACpzdUstKe22TumU1unbgyAjAJ4Tx1PePgCqAE1rq1UqhVhJ7FsQB4Bn8LN8Qr90HVInFEsswdZVi4ci8YQV4YJESdvABFADKkRBtzS6ScT1e3l2DDIJORIF2AA10c1QXcnKtKD03AS4egKXAcOzqugipEKTSVh1MrZKPZbEz0AB5KCYGWnXZUpVg2w9aw5TJakAAOTYxAN3guNpNd1s2Sy1sicCgjvQ0SKADVXWlrLj0qLYTtfP5AtZJrKQDUKVyQ6gw2qen0xdGSmVrPGfonKbs0-chRrrSNDoWkYmANLagCSZdWj1W1v2NYTp0BcxdGJuyvsVaQXwLPe8fcWg-5aScjjEmpzbx8CInRdO9YAMtqEgBdRIqfRQUY0HCYdjyWZsNhkQRwADkEAABBBMGwoABrF8HGhQOAX3tOBRhfS9wkoYJiCgOQoDUIxQHgGgyCwGwxBHEBBDHECEJAOBZBg5QaFkMg0FAAAPMiQAAMxoOBBGUbwo0KJQZFGdpZAYQRBCUTAPhwU5ZDYBBiJ0JoQA+KjaPoxj0DnVi4IfKiAC8QLYNBqJ0CA4CPPiBO8ABHBh-EvdRL1IBIj2QUYvyo4RZGmTBRj0JQcDYYj2iclyQA-NhBEvHA0C8uBeP404xjgFB4nifdeNGfwIGothRgQXDaP8nDNBAHAxjCbwmGciBCmi2KQAAdxoZRoxgywkGInDB3wwjiNIrKYMEZKqO0XRTmEFDMBmeLJKPSisqQciaAMLKsKYeips0wRtN4-8v3mrSQp8uglNQTjuKPaSGKYwlWOSjiuJ4nywu8ISRNCQRLKUJD+rQFwMOs2ysrYHKoDoSTUAwvTwtGSLxJy+KECm4w61OAqGCK4JtIfPUqKatgiJIyGQEo0qnISrDMEc5yNsB7wPJA7rLNKiqqreGr1Hq0YD3iIA)

I want chart not distorted on using scroller(when i drag on scroller and double/single click on the same sroller then chart look same as previous without drag on scroller) and x axis label maintain a sorting order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Count": 210.64, "month": "Jan-21", "name": "DRC"},
      {"Count": 179.95, "month": "Feb-21", "name": "WER"},
      {"Count": 155.48, "month": "Mar-21", "name": "GHJ"},
      {"Count": 230.72, "month": "Apr-21", "name": "THE"},
      {"Count": 167.27, "month": "May-21", "name": "JUY"},
      {"Count": 35.02, "month": "Jun-21", "name": "EDC"},
      {"Count": 234.97, "month": "Jul-21", "name": "QSD"},
      {"Count": 176.2, "month": "Aug-21", "name": "AXC"},
      {"Count": 163.84, "month": "Sep-21", "name": "FDS"},
      {"Count": 191.01, "month": "Oct-21", "name": "ASD"},
      {"Count": 182.99, "month": "Nov-21", "name": "THN"},
      {"Count": 119.79, "month": "Dec-21", "name": "RFV"},
      {"Count": 124.74, "month": "Jan-22", "name": "WSX"},
      {"Count": 241.88, "month": "Feb-22", "name": "QSA"},
      {"Count": 163.01, "month": "Mar-22", "name": "KOI"},
      {"Count": 137.3, "month": "Apr-22", "name": "YHN"},
      {"Count": 0, "month": "May-22", "name": "YHJ"},
      {"Count": 160.51, "month": "Jun-22", "name": "KLO"}
    ]
  },
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "height": 250,
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "month", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {
              "field": "Count",
              "scale": {"zero": false},
              "type": "quantitative"
            }, "order":{"sort": "ascending", "field":"id"}
          },
          "mark": {"line": true, "point": true, "tooltip": true, "type": "area"}
        }
      ],
      "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "brush"}}],
      "width": "container"
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"value": "lightGray"},
        "x": {
          "axis": {"labels": false, "ticks": false, "title": null},
          "field": "month",
          "sort": null,
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      },
      "height": 40,
      "mark": {"opacity": 0, "type": "area"},
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "brush",
          "select": {"encodings": ["x"], "translate": true, "type": "interval"}
        }
      ],
      "width": "container"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks once again Davide , it work for me.
can u please explain the logic behind order by used in y-axis only?

Comment: That is how VL sorts the data points on a line chart and decides the order in which to connect them.

Comment: thanks ,i got it

Comment: your above solution not working for month(timeseries) , do double click on scroller[vconcat-1] left or right side on scroller,sort on label is not correct,please help

Comment: Ask a new question with full details.

Comment: here is the link of new question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598521/sorting-issue-in-area-chart-of-vegalite